# SSRS expression multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to build a SSRS expression on a tablix. Its using two Parameters: Product which has {A,B,C,D} as products and Qtr as quarters 1,2,3,4 and Amounts as 1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000. I'm trying to add an extra condition to Product A by saying if the Product is A and qtr is 4 then the Amt is 2000 if not the Amt is 3000. The following expression is giving me #Error in the tablix. I don't know what is wrong.

```
=iif(Parameters!Product.count=2,1000,iif(Parameters!Product.Value(0)="A" AND Parameters!Qtr.Value(0)=4,2000,iif(Parameters!Product.Value(0)="A",3000,iif(Parameters!Product.Value(0)="B",4000,iif(Parameters!Product.Value(0)="C",5000,iif(Parameters!Product.Value(0)="D",6000,7000))))))
```

Comment: There will be more details about the error in the output panel at the bottom of Visual Studio. Have a look at the error there, and if it that doesn't help, add it to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but it worked in my test case. I'm not exactly sure why, but the references to `Parameters!Product.Value(0)` are causing the issue. Doesn't make sense to me, since based on your expression checking for count = 2 it must be a multi-value parameter, which means it cannot be null, so there will always be a Value(0). You can put `=Parameters!Product.Value(0)` in a text box by itself, but putting it in a conditional causes a problem apparently.

First of all, Switch is much better suited to this task than nested IIf, so that is what I used instead. That doesn't have anything to do with the error, but it is much more readable and easier to understand.

To get around the issue with referencing `Parameters!Product.Value(0)` within the conditional, I created a comma separated string of the parameter values, and then took just the first character from that string with `Left(Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ","), 1)`. If the actual values for Product are a variable amount of characters, you would need to modify that to parse the value before the first comma, but since your values are A, B, C, and D this will work. So the full expression would look like this:

```
=switch(
    Parameters!Product.Count = 2, 1000,
    Left(Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ","), 1) = "A" and Parameters!Qtr.Value = 4, 2000,
    Left(Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ","), 1) = "A", 3000,
    Left(Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ","), 1) = "B", 4000,
    Left(Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ","), 1) = "C", 5000,
    Left(Join(Parameters!Product.Value, ","), 1) = "D", 6000,
    true, 7000
)
```

Comment: @C Black thanks! The error is gone, but when I change the Qtr to 4 in the dropdown the Amount still shows 3000 instead of 2000.

Comment: And you have "A" selected for Product? I get 2000 on my test report when I use A for Product and 4 for Qtr; I also still get 2000 when I have Qtr 4 along with any 3 Products selected as long as one of them is A (doesn't work for 2 Products since that returns 1000 regardless of Qtr)

Comment: Sorry the Amt that says 3000 should actually be 1000. I'm getting 7000 for Product A and Qtr 4. If I select all I get 1000.

Comment: Did you modify the expression at all? Is Qtr also a multi-value parameter or is it single (I assumed single in my testing)? Just trying to narrow down where the issue could be since it works for me. The only way to get 7000 with this expression is if none of the conditions are met, so if you are getting 7000 then it is somehow not meeting any of the first 6 conditions.

Comment: Ah so your Product values are actually 2 characters long. The expression I gave only grabs the first character, so essentially even when there should be a match, the expression is seeing "A" = "AA" which is false, instead of "AA" = "AA" which would be true. Change the 1's in the Left() statements to 2's and you should be good to go.

Comment: Perfect! Awesome thanks so much it worked when I changed it to 2.

Comment: do you have any idea, I'm trying to show Qtr for 24 months back in the past on tablix. 
=Parameters!Year.Value*100+(Parameters!Qtr.Value <= (DateAdd("m", 24, today())))   my Year is 2018

Answer (score 0):

instead of implementing with IIF try with the switch statement.
which make coding simple and manageable in long-term

example:
=switch
(
Fields!filestatus.Value="P","lightGreen"
,isnothing(Fields!filestatus.Value),"IndianRed"
,true,"No Color"
)